# Can we add a round corner edge on line created using pen tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes, stroke

Can a rounded stroke be given to a line/ shape created using pen tool?

See the Image for your reference...
[image]

> Currently what I have done is I drew another line rounded that and put on the top of it.

[image: Image2]

Like this, But that is not the appropriate way every time, especially when the shape something similar to shown as the first one.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, simply adjust the **Caps** option, setting it to rounded, in the **Stroke Options**.

[image]

Comment: this is not applicable for pen tool. I guess

Comment: @SumitYadav How is it not applicable for the pen tool? I do this all the time. The Pen Tool merely draws *paths* which have *no appearance*. It's the stroke, and stroke options which control any *visible* aspect a path may have. Without a stroke or fill, a path can't be seen.